# How can I change the font family of pasted URLs in textedit in Mac

Tags: macos, fonts, copy-paste, url, textedit

since a few weeks I have the problem that when I use textedit on Mac the font that I use in the document is different to the one that is used when I paste a link in it.

I use Helvetica in the document and then when I paste a link in it instead Times is being used and also 2 sizes smaller then the rest of the documents font size. Even when I paste it just behind a word that is Font size 14 and Helvetica its inserted in Times and size 12.

Thanks in advance,
Atilla

Answer (score 0):

Edit Menu > Paste and Match Style -  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>    <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>

This will match your existing style, inc font, size, colour, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Fun fact I was just searching again for an answer and found my own post. But there is no option to set the styles somewhere that it always matches with the rest of the document?